# iOS Todays Widget Extension - Animate UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, ios8-today-widget

I'm creating todays extension within iOS. 
What I'm trying to do is to animate value change on UISlider added in todays extension. 
Animation should proceed from start value to end value.

I tried to do it in two ways:
First UIView animation

```
func updateSliderView(beginState:Float, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    sliderView.hidden = false
    sliderView.setValue(beginState, animated: false)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) { () -> Void in
        self.sliderView.setValue(1, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Second with Basic Animation.

```
func updateSliderView(beginState:Float, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    sliderView.hidden = false
    guard let _ = sliderView.layer.animationForKey("slider.animation.value") else {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "value")
        animation.fromValue = beginState
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.removedOnCompletion = true
        sliderView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "slider.animation.value")
        return
    }
}
```

I'm doing it with new XCode 7.0.1 with iOS target 8.1
**In both result ends without animation.** UISlider have User interaction disabled. 
I'm using UISluder because I have custom graphics for slider path min & max track and for the slider thumb.

I did third test

```
sliderView.setValue(beginState, animated: false)
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)
sliderView.setValue(1, animated: true)
CATransaction.commit()
```

it wont work :/

Summary: Only UIView.animation works. It's animating but it's breaking my customs graphic for UISlider and it's not setting start value for slider.

**How can I animate UISlider value change in Todays extension??**

Comment: Doesn't slider have a set value animated method? Did you try that?

Comment: I did use corect method with animation
As you can see in 1st code example, animated:true, It wont animate it :( thats why I'm here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved it out. 
I answer my own question because maybe it will help to somebody and it's the solution I was asking for.

Only UIView.animation are animating UISlider inside *Todays Extension*. But setting starting value was not working before animation and the animation was breaking custom graphics on slider. 
I figured it out when you set starting value in UIView.animation block everthing will work as I wanted.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.sliderView.setValue(beginState, animated: true)
        }) { (completed) -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.1, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.sliderView.setValue(1, animated: true)
                }, completion: nil)
    }
```

I combined two blocks of UIView animation. The result was as I expected before. 
starting value was set. UISlider value was animated from starting value to the end. All custom graphics like min, max and thumb were rendered correctly.